# Add class to a var jquery

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

This may very well be quite butchered in various places, but hopefully I could get an answer nontheless.

I've got two tabs. When I click Tab1 I want to add a CSS class to Tab2.
Only one tab is clickable at a time, so when Tab1 is clicked, it becomes 'unclickable' and the other tab can be clicked instead.

I was thinking to create a function and pass those two tabs as parameters in a jQuery function but I don't think this is the right way of doing it... Here's the code:

```
    function toggleTabs(tabClicked,otherTab){
    var tabClicked = tabClicked;
    var otherTab = otherTab;    
    if(tabClicked).hasClass("regLogPassive") {
        tabClicked.addClass("regLogActive");
        otherTab.removeClass("regLogActive");
    } else {
        return();
    }
}

$(".tab1").click(function() {
    toggleTabs($(".tab1"), $(".tab2"));
});

$(".tab2").click(function() {
    toggleTabs($(".tab2"), $(".tab1"));
});
```

Comment: So does the code you've shown work, or give an error, or...? What's the question? Note that you don't need to re-declare the function parameters with `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tri this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">tab1</div>
<div class="tab">tab2</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".tab").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("active")){
        return;
    }

    $(".tab.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error which would be stopping your code execute.  Your code seems alright.

Change

```
  return();
```

To

```
   return;
```